# Listing JSON object and key in Jinja2

Tags: json, jinja2

I have a json file like this:

```json
[
    {
    "as": 65011,
    "peers": {
      "swp1": {
        "hostname": "Spine-01",
        "remoteAs": 65001
      },
      "swp2": {
        "hostname": "Spine-02",
        "remoteAs": 65001
      }
    },
    "routerId": "10.0.0.3",
    "peerCount": 2
    }
]
```

Using Jinja2, I want to convert it in txt format like this:

```
Peers :
   Interface : swp1
   Hostname : Spine-1
   AS : 65001
   Interface : swp2
   Hostname : Spine-2
   AS : 65001
```

I used jsonpath to validate it. The template I use is like this:

```
{% for item in get_devices.json.results -%}
Peers :
   Interface : {{ item.peers.*~ }}
   Hostname : {{ item.peers.[*].hostname }}
   AS : {{ item.peers.[*].remoteAs }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, this results in errors due to the `*`, `[]`, and `~` characters. What changes should I make to run this properly and produce the appropriate output?

Comment: That's simply not jinja syntax -- jinja does not support jsonpath expressions like that. The [template documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 is not related to JSONPath anyhow, so you cannot use its syntax here.

What you are looking to achieve, though, is easily doable having a second `for` loop to [iterate over the `peers` dictionary](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for):

```
{% for item in get_devices.json.results -%}
Peers :
{%- for interface, peer in item.peers.items() %}
   Interface : {{ interface }}
   Hostname : {{ peer.hostname }}
   AS : {{ peer.remoteAs }}
{%- endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Produces:

```
Peers :
   Interface : swp1
   Hostname : Spine-01
   AS : 65001
   Interface : swp2
   Hostname : Spine-02
   AS : 65001
```